# Launch R code from within vim-r-plugin as separate window instead of inside tmux/screen?

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, tmux, r

I use the `vim-r-plugin` to write `R` code in `vim`. It is a nice plugin and I love that the plugin lets me run code directly from within `vim`.

However, the `R` prompt is opened in a console which is attached to `vim` using `tmux` and the `vim` screen plugin. This limits my choices when it comes to window management. I would prefer if the `R` console was in it's own window so that my window manager (awesome) can handle the windows separately. Is there any way to do this?

I would be satisfied if it was possible to pop out a running terminal from `screen`/`tmux` to run in it's own window using some shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

When I used `tmux` before opened .R file, then the R console was embedded in the same window after `\rf`.

On the other hand, open .R file directly before tmux session opened, then it could pop a separate R console windows if `\rf`

It is my experience, not a solution.